# How to call a static function defined in other js to content js file in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Requirement:** To pass dynamic values to chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem) to get listed on webpage right click;

**Usecase:**

1. create a static **contextMenu** function in **script.js**
2. **content.js** will fetch dynamic value from a webpage for example: textarea className
3. I want to pass this **className** as contextMenuItem to    `chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem)` defined in script.js so that it will get listed as contextMenu item on right click from a webpage.

**manifest.json**

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "finder",
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "host_permissions": ["https://vder/"],
      
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "run_at" : "document_idle",
        "all_frames": true,
        "matches":[ 
        "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js":["jquery-3.1.1.min.js","content.js", "script.js"]
      }
    ],
    "permissions":["contextMenus"],
    
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js", "script.js"]
        },
        
        "browser_action":{
            "default_icon": "finder.png"
        }
}
```

**script.js**

```
function dynamicContext(contextMenuName){
    var contextMenuItem = {
        "id": "addRecipe",
        "title": contextMenuName,
        "contexts": ["all"]
    }
    return contextMenuItem;
}

chrome.contextMenus.create(dynamicContext);
```

**content.js**

```
classname = 'textarea login'; //class name of login textarea
webElement = classname; 

How do I pass webElement value above to dynamicContext() defined in script.js?
```